# How to assertion a void method in Robolectric Unit Test

Tags: android, unit-testing, robolectric, android-testing

How to verify a void method call in Robolectric test case where as no data coming out the called method.

What to assert in this case? Below given an example of the requirement.

```
public class SampleClass(){

    final String TAG = SampleClass.class.getSimpleName();

    public void log(){
        Log.d(TAG, "Entry Loggd");
    }

}

@Test
public void logEntry_test(){

    SampleClass sc = new SampleClass();
    sc.log();

    // What to assert here to verify this log method

}
```

Comment: What are you trying to assert? 
The log message? 
That the Log.d() method was invoked? 
That the log() method executed with no exceptions?

Answer (score 3):

First off, good on you for writing tests!!! There are a few ways to go about testing that an internal logger is called. It's equally as important to **understand what you're looking to test.** Testing that a class is logging a specific message is most likely a [fragile test](http://xunitpatterns.com/Fragile%20Test.html), so be fore-warned that you probably don't need it.

#### Method #1: Using Robolectric

Robolectic documentation doesn't lend itself to answering basic questions, but its codebase is very well documented with its tests. A basic understanding of its principles and [how shadows work](http://robolectric.org/extending/) can get you a long way.  [ShadowLog tests](https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/blob/master/robolectric/src/test/java/org/robolectric/shadows/ShadowLogTest.java) lay the ground work to this solution.

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
public class SampleClassTest {
    @Test
    public void log_writesExpectedMessage() {
        new SampleClass().log();

        ShadowLog.LogItem lastLog = ShadowLog.getLogs().get(0);
        assertThat(lastLog.msg).isEqualTo("some message");
        // or
        assertThat(lastLog.msg).isNotNull();
    }
}
```

*Tests using Robolectric v3.1.2* 
Add the following to your `build.gradle` file:

```
testCompile 'org.robolectric:robolectric:3.1.2'
```

#### Method #2: Making use of Abstractions

If your sample class derives from an Android class (Activity, Fragment, Application, etc), then using `android.util.Log` makes sense, but bear in mind that your test will need to be a Robolectric or AndroidInstrumented test. If your `SampleClass` is just some POJO, then using a simple logging framework may make your testing efforts easier. For example, using Jake Wharton's [Timber](https://github.com/JakeWharton/timber), your class and test can be written as follows:

```
import timber.log.Timber;

public class SampleClass {
    void log() {
        Timber.d("some message");
    }
}

// SampleClassTest.java
public class SampleClassTest {
    // setting up a Tree instance that we define below
    TestTree testTree = new TestTree();

    @Test
    public void log_writesExpectedMessage() {
        // setting up Timber to us the test classes log writer
        Timber.plant(testTree);
        // invoke the logging function
        new SampleClass().log();
        // assert
        assertThat(testTree.lastMessage).isEqualTo("some message");
    }

    private class TestTree extends Timber.Tree {
        private String lastMessage;

        @Override
        protected void log(int priority, String tag, String message, Throwable t) {
            lastMessage = message;
        }
    }
}
```

Good luck, happy testing!

Comment: It sounds like the OP was just giving a method with a log in as a MCVE rather than explicitly trying to test log messages. I'm looking for something similar now — how to verify that void methods are called similar to Mockito verify on mocks

Answer (score 0):

In my understanding you want to mock static methods. I guess, using static mocks are not the most elegant way to testing. Better to use an abstraction as recommended by [abest](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3166366/abest).  Although, it can be done with [PowerMock](https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/mockito#mocking-static-method).